# Is it possible to localise the iOS app partially?

Tags: ios, localization, appstore-approval, localizable.strings

We have a requirement in the iOS application from a client that, we need to localize only one particular feature i.e. some of the screens from the App. The remaining features/screens will always be in English.
Is it allowed from the App Store?

Can anyone confirm this, please? are there any chances of Apple rejecting the app in review?

Comment: It should be fine, it has never caused us any issues to have only certain features in the app localised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective, this is allowable, I don't see anything in [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design) talking about localization.

I've uploaded an App with both Vietnamese and English, and it was approved. This is a small part of the tab bar controller, there are many screens kind of mixing like this.

[image]

Comment: It's no problem.

Comment: just one more query, can we do the same (partial support) with right-to-left support languages? I have a doubt about the default navigations for Right to Left support languages.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the problem with RTL or LTR in this circumstance?

Comment: When I am partially supporting the app for localization, in the case of RTL languages the UINavigationController does the animation from Left To Right and all the other alignments as well like nav bar items. My issue is how to stop the  default RTL components support.

Comment: aw, AFAIK, there is a UIView property named `semanticContentAttribute`, you can force set it to whatever semantic you want, for a specific view.